# Animate() scroll does not allow to see the title

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made the menu sticky, but the problem that i have now it's that menu does not allow me to see the title of the categories.. you can see it here

http://jisparking.cl

i'd like to know how I can move the scroll animation a little top to avoid
that the menu is over the category title..

My code is this:

```
  $(".nav li a").on('click', function(event) {

            // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
            if (this.hash !== "") {
              // Prevent default anchor click behavior
              event.preventDefault();

              // Store hash
              var hash = this.hash;

              // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
              // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
              $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
              }, 800, function(){

                // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
                window.location.hash = hash;
              });
            } // End if
        });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply subtract a value from `scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top`, like `scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 50`

Of course this would break the first link as it would give a negative value. A possible solution is

`scrollTop: Math.max($(hash).offset().top - 50, 0)`

(if the value is negative `Math.max` will return `0` instead)

This to make as little changes as possible to your code, but I think there could be other ways to achieve what you are trying to.